# Can't save any Classes - why?

Tags: apex, error, developer-console

I barely know what I'm doing but I thought I could at least get by...but I have no clue what's going on. I was trying to write a test class which was going fine until all of sudden I was getting an unexpected token '=' error when trying to set a variable.

Not knowing why, I cleared it all out and just wrote this:

```
public class testing123 {
     System.debug('Hello World');
}
```

...which for some reason is now spitting out: "expecting a right parentheses, found 'Hello World'" - huh?

Thus, I don't think the problem has anything to do with my test class and instead something probably fundamental that I seem to have overlooked. Ironically, my Trigger & the Class it calls save fine.

EDIT: Adding actual test class below. The error I'm getting is unexpected token: ';' at line 24, which is "List ctasToInsert..."

```
@isTest
public class CallToActionNoDeleteBusinessReviewTest {

Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account',
                        Type = 'Brand',
                        Industry = 'Auto',
                        Country__c = 'United States');

User assignee = [Select Id
                 From User
                 Where Title Like '%Customer Success Manager%'
                 And IsActive = True
                 Limit 1];

Call_To_Action__c ctaTemp = new Call_To_Action__c(Name = 'Test CTA',
                                                  Account__c = a.Id,
                                                  Assignee__c = assignee.Id,
                                                  Due_Date__c = System.today(),
                                                  Priority__c = 'Medium',
                                                  Reason__c = 'Grow Account',
                                                  Status__c = 'New',
                                                  Type__c = 'Event');

List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToInsert = new List<Call_To_Action__c>;

Call_To_Action__c ebrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
ebrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-EBR';
ctasToInsert.add(ebrCTA);

Call_To_Action__c qbrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
qbrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-QBR';
qbrCTA.QBR_Quarter__c = 1;
ctasToInsert.add(qbrCTA);

insert ctasToInsert;
List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToDelete = [Select Id
                                        From Call_To_Action__c
                                        Where Name = 'Test CTA'];

test.startTest();

System.runAs(assignee) {
    delete ctasToDelete;
}

test.stopTest();
}
```

EDIT 2: Updated, finished test class.

```
@isTest
public class CallToActionNoDeleteBusinessReviewTest {

@testSetup
public static void testRecordCreate() {

    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account',
                            Type = 'Brand',
                            Industry = 'Auto',
                            Country__c = 'United States');
    insert a;

    User assignee = [Select Id
                    From User
                    Where Title Like '%Customer Success Manager%'
                    And IsActive = True
                    Limit 1];

    Call_To_Action__c ctaTemp = new Call_To_Action__c(Name = 'Test CTA',
                                                      Account__c = a.Id,
                                                      Assignee__c = assignee.Id,
                                                      Due_Date__c = System.today(),
                                                      Priority__c = 'Medium',
                                                      Reason__c = 'Grow Account',
                                                      Status__c = 'New',
                                                      Type__c = 'Event');

    List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToInsert = new List<Call_To_Action__c>();

    Call_To_Action__c ebrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
    ebrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-EBR';
    ctasToInsert.add(ebrCTA);

    Call_To_Action__c qbrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
    qbrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-QBR';
    qbrCTA.QBR_Quarter__c = 1;
    ctasToInsert.add(qbrCTA);

    Call_To_Action__c kickOffCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
    kickOffCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-KO';
    ctasToInsert.add(kickOffCTA);

    insert ctasToInsert;        
}

@isTest
static void testAsNonAdmin() {

    List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToDelete = [Select Id
                                            From Call_To_Action__c
                                            Where CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-EBR'
                                            OR CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-QBR'];

    User nonAdmin = [Select Id
                      From User
                      Where Title Like '%Customer Success Manager%'
                      And IsActive = True
                      Limit 1];

    test.startTest();

    System.runAs(nonAdmin) {
        try {
            delete ctasToDelete;
            System.assert(false, 'Exception expected');
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Boolean expectedError = e.getMessage().contains('Business Review CTAs cannot be deleted.');
            System.assert(expectedError);
        }
    }

    test.stopTest();
}

@isTest
static void testAsAdmin() {

    List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToDelete = [Select Id
                                            From Call_To_Action__c
                                            Where CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-EBR'
                                            OR CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-QBR'];

    Profile p = [Select Id From Profile Where Name = 'System Administrator'];
    User admin = [Select Id
                  From User
                  Where ProfileId = :p.Id
                  And IsActive = True
                  Limit 1];

    test.startTest();

    System.runAs(admin) {
        try {
            delete ctasToDelete;
            System.assert(true, 'No Exception. Expected.');
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Boolean expectedError = e.getMessage().contains('Business Review CTAs cannot be deleted.');
            System.assert(!expectedError, 'Unexpected Exception Thrown');
        }
    }

    test.stopTest();
}

@isTest
static void testNonBRAsNonAdmin() {

    List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToDelete = [Select Id
                                            From Call_To_Action__c
                                            Where CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-KO'];

    User nonAdmin = [Select Id
                     From User
                     Where Title Like '%Customer Success Manager%'
                     And IsActive = True
                     Limit 1];

    test.startTest();

    System.runAs(nonAdmin) {
        try {
            delete ctasToDelete;
            System.assert(true, 'No Exception. Expected.');
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Boolean expectedError = e.getMessage().contains('Business Review CTAs cannot be deleted.');
            System.assert(!expectedError, 'Unexpected Exception Thrown');
        }
    }

    test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Comment: You should be writing `System.debug('Hello World');` inside method only then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've provided so far is not a valid class (hence your error). I'd recommend going through the [documentation on Apex classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_understanding.htm), or perhaps the [apex quick start project on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/quickstart-apex) if you're not familiar with Object-Oriented Programming (though that project doesn't go as in-depth as I'd like).

Grossly simplifying things, a class is a container for variables and methods. `System.debug('Hello World');` is neither a variable, nor a method.

To get your provided code to save without error, the easiest way is probably to just put your debug statement into a method like this.

```
public class testing123{
    // Methods that have the 'static' keyword don't need an instance of the class
    //   to be called.
    // I'll get into that some more in a bit...
    public static void myStaticMethod(){
        System.debug('Hello World...but static');
    }

    // The 'public' keyword is an access modifier, it tells Salesforce about
    //   how other things are allowed to call this method.
    // The 'void' keyword here is the return type. When the method finishes doing its
    //   thing, it can return a value to the thing that called it.
    // 'void' is used when we don't want to return anything.
    // Since this method doesn't have the 'static' keyword, it is an 'instance' method,
    //   and can only be called on an instance of the class.
    public void myInstanceMethod(){
        System.debug('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Actually getting your debug statement to print "Hello World" means that you'll need to call the method.

```
// To make an 'instance' of your class, you use the 'new' keyword
MyClass anInstance = new MyClass();

// Once we have an instance of a class, we can call its instance methods
anInstance.myInstanceMethod();

// Static methods cannot be called from an instance.
// They are instead called by specifying the class name, a dot/period/full-stop,
//   and finally the name of the method
MyClass.myStaticMethod();
```

**+edit:**

Now that you've added your actual code, it's a bit more clear what your issue is.

You're trying to make your test class the same way that you make a trigger, which is incorrect. Triggers are a bit of a special case...that is, a trigger doesn't have methods (in fact, you *cannot* define methods in a trigger). When you make a class (and a test class is a special type of class), most of the code needs to be contained within a method.

```
@isTest
public class CallToActionNoDeleteBusinessReviewTest {
    // Variables like these can be defined outside of a method, though best practice
    //   is to put these things inside of a method with the @testSetup annotation.
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account',
                            Type = 'Brand',
                            Industry = 'Auto',
                            Country__c = 'United States');

    // Pretty much everything else needs to go inside of a method.
    // The @isTest annotation isn't required here, but can be helpful.
    // Doing this allows you to "disable" the test by simply commenting out the 
    //   line with the annotation.
    @isTest
    static void myTestMethod(){
        User assignee = [
            Select Id
            From User
            Where Title Like '%Customer Success Manager%'
            And IsActive = True
            Limit 1];

        // Note that you'll need to actually insert your Account before trying to
        //   use a.Id.
        // Unless you explicitly set the Id of an SObject in the constructor,
        //   the Id will be null until after you insert the record.
        Call_To_Action__c ctaTemp = new Call_To_Action__c(
            Name = 'Test CTA',
            Account__c = a.Id,
            Assignee__c = assignee.Id,
            Due_Date__c = System.today(),
            Priority__c = 'Medium',
            Reason__c = 'Grow Account',
            Status__c = 'New',
            Type__c = 'Event'
        );

        // Instantiating a list requires parenthesis just after the '>'
        List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToInsert = new List<Call_To_Action__c>();
        // You could also use curly braces to instantiate if you had a value
        //   to put into the list
        //   for example...
        // List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToInsert = new List<Call_To_Action__c>{ctaTemp};
        Call_To_Action__c ebrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
        ebrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-EBR';
        ctasToInsert.add(ebrCTA);

        Call_To_Action__c qbrCTA = ctaTemp.clone();
        qbrCTA.CTA_Code__c = 'SCH-QBR';
        qbrCTA.QBR_Quarter__c = 1;
        ctasToInsert.add(qbrCTA);

        insert ctasToInsert;
        List<Call_To_Action__c> ctasToDelete = [Select Id
                                            From Call_To_Action__c
                                            Where Name = 'Test CTA'];

        test.startTest();

        System.runAs(assignee) {
            delete ctasToDelete;
        }

        test.stopTest();

        // Your test is missing assertions, which I typically place after test.stopTest();
        // The primary purpose of unit tests is to verify that the thing you're
        //   testing behaved the way you thought it would.
        // Here, that might mean checking to see if records were actually deleted,
        //   or perhaps that certain records were prevented from being deleted
        // An example assertion would be
        //System.assertEquals(true, [SELECT Id FROM Call_To_Action__c].isEmpty(), 'Expected that there would be no call to action records');
    }

    // You can also have more than one method in a class.
    // I'd argue that if you only have one test method, you're not doing enough testing.
    // Breaking things up into separate test methods, and testing one thing at a time,
    //   makes it easier to track what situations you've tested so far.
    // It also makes identifying where problems are a lot easier
    @isTest
    static void mySecondTest(){
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this was a bad example. In my actual test class, I'm first trying to define the test records. As such, I did something along the lines of:
 // 
sObject a = new sObject();
a.FieldName = 'String';
 // 
The error here was unexpected token '='. So even that would need to be within a method?

Comment: @Mike Defining an `SObject` instance, and initializing it, can be done outside of a method...but almost everything else needs to be contained in a method. It really would help if you were to edit your question to include the actual code that you've having trouble with.

Comment: @Mike just finished making my edits

Comment: Thanks Derek - this is fantastic! (I actually wasn't done writing the test yet, hence the lack of assertions and additional tests.) It seems like the initial problems I was having were around not putting things in methods as well as forgetting the () to instantiate a list. I'd be really grateful if you could take a look at my final test class (pasted as second edit to the original question). I'm not so much asking for code review looking for errors, but more as relates to implementing the best practices you mentioned in your comments. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike - You do not have any asserts in the most important test, the positive case in the first test methods :) You don't just assert errors. You need to query for the results and assert that what should have happened did.

Comment: Got, thanks Eric. I've just added assertEquals for the expected number of records after deletion attempts in each test method.